# html form handling inside servlet

Tags: java, html, servlets

I am a complete new t servlet can someone plz tell me what is wrong with my code;i am trying to name input from user in a textbox and then display welcome :"text entered by user in textbox"
here is my code

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

// Extend HttpServlet class
public class myprogramme extends HttpServlet {

  public void service(HttpServletRequest req,HttpServletResponse res)throws ServletException,IOException {       
      res.setContentType("text/html");
      PrintWritter out=res.getWritter();
      String name=req.getParameter("txtname");
      out.println("<b>< font size=8 color="red">" +"welcome:"+ </font> "</b>"+name);
  }

}
```

name of the textbox is txtname which i am storing in name variable

Comment: I don't know which resources you're using to learn about Servlets but seems very strange to teach overriding the `service` method and not using Servlets 3.0 at least. Please upgrade your Servlet resource tutorial and learn the latest of this technology instead. Also, you should avoid printing HTML directly from Servlet.

Comment: Do you config in web.xml ?

Comment: @Jason my web.xml doc   <web-app>
<servlet>
 <servlet-name>servlet3</servlet-name>
 <servlet-class>myprogramme</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>servlet3</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>run1</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>









</web-app>

Answer (score 1):

To answer your specific question, you need to escape your `String` literal (the double quotes surrounding red) and you didn't quote the font close tag (but you could collapse it to a single HTML String) like -

```
out.println("<b><font size=8 color=\"red\">Welcome:</font></b>" + name);
```

That being said, this is not a good way to write Java Servlet today. Because it uses presentation in the Servlet.

**Edit** It's [`getWriter()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletResponse.html#getWriter%28%29), change this

```
PrintWritter out=res.getWritter();
```

to

```
PrintWriter out=res.getWriter();
```

Comment: i am stil getting these two error even after the coorection you said to make-:  myprogramme.java:12: error: cannot find symbol
PrintWritter out=res.getWritter();
^
  symbol:   class PrintWritter
  location: class myprogramme
myprogramme.java:12: error: cannot find symbol
PrintWritter out=res.getWritter();
                    ^
  symbol:   method getWritter()
  location: variable res of type HttpServletResponse
2 errors

Comment: thanks sir but if you can you tell me the better way to write the servlet as you said in your answer, i would be highly grateful to you

Answer (score 0):

True, it is not the best way to do it, but I would suggest you to do like below for you to learn it easily:

```js
  public void service(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws ServletException, IOException {
    res.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter out = res.getWriter();
    String name = req.getParameter("txtname");

    StringBuilder sb = null;

    try {

      sb = new StringBuilder();
      sb.append("<b>< font size='8' color='red'>");
      sb.append(" Welcome : " + name + " </font></b>");

      out.println(sb.toString())

    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }

  }
```

I haven't test it, hope you can get an idea..